# Saving lines between "start"s and "end"s to different arrays

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file that consists of a bunch of things but what I need are numbers between start and end strings: For example :

```
ghghgh
start
23
34
22
12
end
ghbd
wodkkh
234
start
14
56
74
end
```

So, I need two arrays here one containing 23,34,22,12 and one containing 14,56,74. What's the best command to use?

If I only had one start and one end I would be able to use mapfile and awk to obtain that array, but there's many start and ends in the file and I need to save all the arrays.

Comment: what about 234, which is not between start and stop?

Comment: it should be ignored :)

Comment: @Afagh please if you find any of the answers helpful, mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `sed`.

```
sed -n '/start/{:a;N;/end/!ba;s/\n/, /g;s/, [^,][a-z][^,]*//Ig;s/start, //p}'
```

The code will iterate through all chunks between 'start' and 'end' lines.
It will remove all items with non-digit symbols and output each "array" on separate line.

Here is output from your data sample:

```
23, 34, 22, 12                                                                                                                                                           
14, 56, 74
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a small state machine - switching between in block and out of block:

```
awk '/end/{block = 0; print a; a = ""} (block) {a = a " " $0} /start/{block = 1}'
```

If at `end`, leave block, print and empty the accumulator. If in block, accumulate current line. If at start, mark that we're inside a block.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell `awk` to change the output file every time a new sequence starts

```
awk '/start/{i++;f=1;next} /end/{f=0} f{print > "arr"i}' file
```

For the example file, this will create files: `arr1`, `arr2`. Then you can create separated arrays with the lines of these files:

```
for i in $( ls arr* ); do readarray -t $i < $i; done
```

note: I have assumed that all lines between matching patterns are numeric and acceptable as in the example.

Comment: Please don't use `for i in $(ls ..)` construction. Just please don't. Any file with special symbols or space in the name will break it. Use `for i in arr*` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you trust your input files enough for an eval:

```
$ cat tst.sh
eval $(
    awk '
        f {
            if ( /end/ ) {
                print "declare arr" ++cnt "=(" vals " )"
                vals = ""
                f = 0
            }
            else {
                vals = vals OFS $0
            }
        }
        /start/ { f = 1 }
    ' "$1"
)

printf "arr1:%s\n" "${arr1[@]}"
printf "arr2:%s\n" "${arr2[@]}"

$ ./tst.sh file
arr1:23
arr1:34
arr1:22
arr1:12
arr2:14
arr2:56
arr2:74
```

Check the quoting and all other shell gotchas...

Comment: Thanks for your response. If i=100 how can I access arr100?  and How can I access A[i][j]   jth element of ith array. Thanks